# how to read new message of specific number in android sms

Tags: android

i am using broadcast receiver to read new incoming sms. my problem is when new sms from a contact recieves, my codes can not returns the last message of my contact, it returns the message before last one.
please help me to correct my codes. i am really confused.

```
  public static class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                if (bundle != null) {
                   readVerificationCodeFromInbox();

                }
            }
        }
    }

  public static void readVerificationCodeFromInbox() {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor c = cr.query(message, null, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")) == null) {
                        c.moveToNext();
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).equalsIgnoreCase("9101620")){
                        long date = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));

                        Log.d("date-->", "" + date);
                        String Body =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();

                        String numberOnly= Body.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                        Log.d("Body-->", "" + numberOnly);
                        if (currentTime-date<0.25*3600*1000) {
                            confirm_number.setText(numberOnly);

//                            EnterVerificationCode(numberOnly);
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.retry_get_verificationCode_time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            c.close();
            context.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the priority of your receiver in AndroidManifest.xml? I faced the same issue because I chose a positive priority where my receiver had more priority than the default Android SMS receiver. So what actually happened was, I tried to read the message before the android SMS receiver and put it into the default SMS database which we are accessing over content resolver.

Try choosing priority to be a negative value and it should work.

PS: This should be a comment but could not post it as I dont have enough reputation.

Comment: i didnt register my reciever in manifest. but i add this filterSms.setPriority(-100); in my code but not work :(